# OpenGL 4 core profile, shaders and MFC

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I'm trying to get shaders to work in an MFC app with an OpenGL 4 core profile.

I did this in a Win32 app to make sure it works (it does, drawing a triangle in the lower part of the window):

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   m_hDC = ::GetDC(hWnd);

   PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
   memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
   pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
   pfd.nVersion = 1;
   pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
   pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
   pfd.cColorBits = 32;
   pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
   pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

   int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(m_hDC, &pfd);

   if (nPixelFormat == 0) return false;

   BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd);

   if (!bResult) return false;

   HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(m_hDC);
   wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, tempContext);

   GLenum err = glewInit();
   if (GLEW_OK != err)
   {
       MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)L"Glew not initialized", (LPCWSTR)L"Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
   }

   //Get a GL 4,2 context
   int attribs[] =
   {
       WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
       WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
       WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,
       0
   };

   if (wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1)
   {
       m_hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_hDC, 0, attribs);
       wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
       wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
       wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
   }
   else
   {    //It's not possible to make a GL 4.x context. Use the old style context (GL 2.1 and before)
       m_hRC = tempContext;
   }


   if (!m_hRC) return false;

   static const char * vs_source[] =
   {
       "#version 420 core                                                 \n"
       "                                                                  \n"
       "void main(void)                                                   \n"
       "{                                                                 \n"
       "    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4( 2.25, -2.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
       "                                   vec4(-2.25, -2.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
       "                                   vec4( 2.25,  2.25, 0.5, 1.0)); \n"
       "                                                                  \n"
       "    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                          \n"
       "}                                                                 \n"
   };

   static const char * fs_source[] =
   {
       "#version 420 core                                                 \n"
       "                                                                  \n"
       "out vec4 color;                                                   \n"
       "                                                                  \n"
       "void main(void)                                                   \n"
       "{                                                                 \n"
       "    color = vec4(1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);                             \n"
       "}                                                                 \n"
   };

   program = glCreateProgram();
   GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
   glShaderSource(fs, 1, fs_source, NULL);
   glCompileShader(fs);

   GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
   glShaderSource(vs, 1, vs_source, NULL);
   glCompileShader(vs);

   glAttachShader(program, vs);
   glAttachShader(program, fs);

   glLinkProgram(program);

   glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
   glBindVertexArray(vao);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}


const GLfloat green[] = { 0.0f, 0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        //hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...

        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);

        glUseProgram(program);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        SwapBuffers(m_hDC);

        //EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I did the same in an MFC MDI program and although the background gets cleared to the same color as the Win32 app, the shaders don't draw anything.

For completion, here's the relevant code in my MFC MDI view class (it's different from the code in the Win32 app because I've been trying to figure out what's wrong, but it was once the same as the Win32 app code and it didn't work):

```
int CMFCApplication2View::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    // TODO:  Add your specialized creation code here
    m_hDC = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(m_hDC, &pfd);

    if (nPixelFormat == 0) return false;

    BOOL bResult = SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd);

    if (!bResult) return false;

    HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(m_hDC);
    wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, tempContext);


    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("GLEW is not initialized!"));
    }

    //This is a modern pixel format attribute list.
    //It has an extensible structure. Just add in more argument pairs 
    //befroe the null to request more features.
    const int attribList[] =
    {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB, WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        0, 0  //End
    };


    unsigned int numFormats;
    int pixelFormat;
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));

    //Select a pixel format number
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(m_hDC, attribList, NULL, 1, &pixelFormat, &numFormats);

    //Optional: Get the pixel format's description. We must provide a 
    //description to SetPixelFormat(), but its contents mean little.
    //According to MSDN: 
    //  The system's metafile component uses this structure to record the logical
    //  pixel format specification. The structure has no other effect upon the
    //  behavior of the SetPixelFormat function.
    //DescribePixelFormat(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), pixelFormat, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);

    //Set it as the current 
    if (FALSE == SetPixelFormat(m_hDC, pixelFormat, &pfd))
    {

    }



    //Get a GL 4,4 context
    int attribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        //WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0, 0  //End
    };

    if (wglewIsSupported("WGL_ARB_create_context") == 1)
    {
        m_hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(m_hDC, 0, attribs);
        wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
        wglDeleteContext(tempContext);
        wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);
    }
    else
    {   //It's not possible to make a GL 4.x context. Use the old style context (GL 2.1 and before)
        m_hRC = tempContext;
    }


    if (!m_hRC) return false;

    static const char * vs_source[] =
    {
        "#version 150 core                                                 \n"
        "                                                                  \n"
        "void main(void)                                                   \n"
        "{                                                                 \n"
        "    const vec4 vertices[] = vec4[](vec4( 2.25, -2.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
        "                                   vec4(-2.25, -2.25, 0.5, 1.0),  \n"
        "                                   vec4( 2.25,  2.25, 0.5, 1.0)); \n"
        "                                                                  \n"
        "    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];                          \n"
        "}                                                                 \n"
    };

    static const char * fs_source[] =
    {
        "#version 150 core                                                 \n"
        "                                                                  \n"
        "out vec4 color;                                                   \n"
        "                                                                  \n"
        "void main(void)                                                   \n"
        "{                                                                 \n"
        "    color = vec4(1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0);                             \n"
        "}                                                                 \n"
    };

    program = glCreateProgram();
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, fs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, vs_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);

    glLinkProgram(program);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

    return 0;
}



void CMFCApplication2View::OnDraw(CDC*/* pDC*/)
{
    CMFCApplication2Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here
    // Make the rendering context current
    wglMakeCurrent(m_hDC, m_hRC);

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here 
    static const GLfloat green[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, green);

    glUseProgram(program);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    SwapBuffers(m_hDC);

    // Allow other rendering contexts to coexist
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);

}
```

I ran both executables through AMD's GPU Perfstudio. The Win32 frame debug show everything is ok. The MFC frame debug shows the frame buffer with a size of 0 (the frame buffer size of the win32 app is the size of the window). Both apps API traces are the same.

Any idea on what might be going on?

Comment: It is invalid to call `SetPixelFormat (...)` more than once on the same HDC (unless you use the same pixel format all times). This is why most of the time when software does what you're trying to do on Win32, it creates and destroys a dummy window and then creates the actual window using `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`.

Comment: In the Win32 code I'm only setting the pixel format once. In the MFC code I'm setting it two times (following from an example here: http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/315/WWW/Lab1/MFC/), but doing it exactly like in the Win32 code didn't work either.

Could you please point me towards a working MFC sample? These seem to have vanished from the internet :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently OpenGL in MFC, when using a core profile, needs to have a view port set, via glViewport.

Handling `WM_SIZE` and doing `glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)cx, (GLsizei)cy)` solved the issue.

As a note, Andon was correct in saying that I shouldn't specify the pixel format twice. It didn't give any error, which is strange, but when I removed it everything kept on working.

Comment: You might accept your answer since it is standalone and not depended on external references (which might rot), perhaps you could expand a little.

Comment: FWIW, I suspect the difference with MFC is that you're doing the initialization before the window is actually visible, whereas in the first listing you're fully creating the window before initializing it. Refer to the documentation for `WM_CREATE`...

Comment: @Shog9 I think you're right, but as you probably know WM_CREATE is sent when CreateWindowEx is called, and with MFC it's not trivial (if possible at all) to call code just after CreateWindowEx has finished its job. Furthermore, with a non core OpenGL profile, there's no issue at all, and MFC and OpenGL get along fine with no glViewport. This issue only appears with core OpenGL profiles and MFC.

Comment: Yeah; IIRC, you can also work around this by overriding MFC's creation methods, but that has other gotchas - your solution is fine, as long as you're careful - WM_SIZE can be called a *lot* in some scenarios, and you won't always need to reset the viewport.

Comment: Agreed. Overriding MFC's creation methods wouldn't be trivial, mostly due to the fact that window messages don't arrive in a deterministic way. Creating an OnPostCreate handler is much harder than simply calling glViewport.

Not resizing the viewport when the window size is changed is an application decision, i.e. you either want the content to scale or get clipped. Could you please illustrate any situations where I need to be careful?